# Using Poisson formula to get an inequality about a harmonic function.

Tags: complex-analysis

$f$ is a non-negative real-valued harmonic function in the disc $D = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < R\}$. Prove that

$ \frac{R-|z|}{R+|z|} f(0) \leq f(z) \leq \frac{R+|z|}{R-|z|}f(0)$

whenever $|z| < R$, by using the Poisson formula.

By using the version of Poisson formula with $Re$ in it, I am able to get that $f(z) \leq \frac{R+|z|}{R-|z|}f(0)$. However, I am terrible with inequalities and feel like I am missing something minor to get the second part of the inequality...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z=re^{i\phi}$ and wlog. $R=1$. Then we estimate the real part of the Poisson kernel:

$$\mathrm{Re} \frac{e^{it}+z}{e^{it}-z}=\frac{1-r^2}{1-2r\cos(\phi-t)+r^2}\ge \frac{1-r^2}{1+2r+r^2}=\frac{(1-r)(1+r)}{(1+r)^2}=\frac{1-r}{1+r}$$